# Ajax Scroll to load posts items running function but not loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues with my script. What I'm trying to do is firstly pull a new post in view on button click and then bring into view, then reset the original container (this works).

The issue I'm facing is when I want to load that posts content on scroll (custom fields). My script seems to run but has issues loading the post content. See code below.

HTML:
post-one.html

```
<div id="default" class="main">
    <div id="imageContainer" style="background:url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/next-post" class="button"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="introContentContainer" class="content">
        <div class="postContent-1 post">
            <h1>heading</h1>
            <p>paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="postContentContainer" class="content"></div>
</div>

<div id="load" class="direction"></div>
```

HTML:
next-post.html

```
<div id="default" class="main">
    <div id="imageContainer" style="background:url(images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/post-one" class="button"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="introContentContainer" class="content">
        <div class="postContent-1 post">
            <h1>heading</h1>
            <p>paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="postContentContainer" class="content">
        <div class="postContent-2 post">
            <h2>Content Two</h2>
            <p>para 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent-3 post">
             <h2>Content Three</h2>
             <p>para 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent-4 post">
            <h2>Content Four</h2>
            <p>para 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="load" class="direction"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var processing;
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        history.pushState({ path: this.path }, '', this.href);
        history.replaceState({ path: this.path }, '', this.href);
        RightSlide(self);           
        return false;
    });

    function RightSlide(self) {

        //Unbind Scroll Event
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        console.log('unbind scroll');

        // Get next link URL
        var post_id = $(self).attr('href');

        // Load new top content in offset slide
        $.get(post_id, {}, function(data) {
            var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
            var $image = $response.find('#imageContainer')
            var $content = $response.find('#introContentContainer')
            $('.direction').append($image).append($content);;
            setTimeout(function(){$('.direction').show('slide',{direction: 'right', easing: 'easeOutCubic'}, 600);$('.main').hide('slide', { direction: 'left', easing: 'easeOutCubic' }, 600);},100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Reset slider                 
                if($('#default').hasClass('main')) {
                    $('#default').addClass('direction').removeClass('main');
                } else {
                    $('#default').addClass('main').removeClass('direction');
                }
                if($('#load').hasClass('main')) {
                    $('#load').addClass('direction').removeClass('main');   
                } else {
                    $('#load').addClass('main').removeClass('direction');
                }
                $('.direction').empty().hide();
                $('.disableClicks').hide();
            },700);
            setScroll();
            console.log('bind scroll');
            return false;
        },'html');
    };

    function setScroll() {
        $(document).bind('scroll', function(e){
            if (processing)
                return false;
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10){
                processing = true;
                console.log('the function is processing ' + processing);
                getResults();
            }
        }); 
    }

    function getResults() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        console.log(url);
        $('#postContentContainer').load(url + ' .postContent-2', function(){
            count++;
            console.log('why doesnt this run!');
            return false;
        });
        console.log('run scroll function');
        processing = false; 
    }
```

Here is a run down of the steps so far:

1) click button, load new post off view.

2) slide into viewport, slide out old container & reset classes.

3) on scroll fetch new page post div ".postContent-2"(this will be dynamic eventually) however this fails.

Can anyone see why this doesn't work? And can anyone help with a solution?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Why are you loading the div content that way? As far as i see, that div belongs to the page itself. Can't you do $('#postContentContainer").html($(".postContent-2")) ??

Comment: The div belongs to content I want to fetch, using .html() does not pull the content because nothing is populated in the initial page.

Comment: But with your code you are getting the page you are viewing. You are not getting the page containing the new-post.

Comment: on the button click it changes the url using history push state telling the browser the string has changed but the page isnt reloaded, so the .load() is trying to pull content from the newly changed url which is the next post. The same issue happens with this $('#postContentContainer').load('example.com/new-post' + ' .postContent-2', function(){

Comment: I am not sure if it can be a problem but taking a closer look at your code, you forgot to close a div tag "<div class="postContent-2 post">" ... may be it is causing the .load function to have problems parsing the html.

Comment: Sorry, I formatted wrong, the closing div is still there, just not justified

Answer (score 0):

Got this working!

changed my getResults function to this

```
function getResults() {
    var url = window.location.href;
        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {

            var html = jQuery('<div>').html(data);
            var $newcontent = html.find('.postContent-2');

            $('#introContentContainer').append($newcontent);
            console.log('this now runs!');
            return false;
        }
    });

    console.log('run scroll function');
    processing = false; 
}
```